# Pdfplumber cannot recognize table

Tags: python, dataframe, pdfplumber

`image.reset().debug_tablefinder()`

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mx3W.png)

how to convert it into tables that can be recognized by pdfplumber?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.